# how to create a 2-d array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I tried doing with list but what I actually want to know can we create using array package in python
example
from array import *
a=array('I')

## This will create a array of 1-D how can I do to create a 2-D array or is the only way of creating 2d #array using list

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not using `numpy`? `np.zeros((first_dim,second_dim))` will create you a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with array module. For mathematical operations you indeed should use numpy. array.array is just a wrapper for C arrays.